# Python: take an entry from a list of named tuples if contains particular attribute value

Tags: python, list, namedtuple

I have a `list` of `namedtuples` as below

```
fruits = Fruits['type', 'color', 'weight', 'sweetness']
f1 = fruits('apple', 'red', 1.89, 5)
f1 = fruits('pear', 'green', 2.89, 7)
f1 = fruits('banana', 'yellow', 2.01, 10)

l = [f1, f2, f3]
```

Now, I want to have a function which returns a particular `namedtuple` from the list given a `type`. I wrote this function using a for loop, but is it possible to do it better (faster or without for loop)?

```
def take_fruit(type, all_fruits):
    for f in all_fruits:
        if f.type == type:
           return f
    return None
```

Comment: `next((f for f in all_fruits if f.type == type), None)` but not sure if it's  faster.

Comment: There's several ways to do this, but I don't think any are particularily faster than your variant.

You could use `filter` or a list comprehension if you want to get rid of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter` or list comprehension to make the code *shorter*, although not necessarily *faster*:

```
def take_fruit_listcomp(type, all_fruits):
    try:
        return [f for f in all_fruits if f.type == type][0]
    except IndexError:
        return None

def take_fruit_filter(type, all_fruits):
    try:
        # no need for list(..) if you use Python 2
        return list(filter(lambda f: f.type == type, all_fruits))[0]
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method only if there are no duplicate types. You can use dictionaries for this.

```
d = {
"apple" : fruits('apple', 'red', 1.89, 5),
"pear" : fruits('pear', 'green', 2.89, 7),
"banana" : fruits('banana', 'yellow', 2.01, 10)
}

def take_fruit(type)
    return list(d[type])
```

Here, the dictionary stores type as key. This is faster in this way

Comment: What if there are 2 apples?

Comment: Added a constraint in the beginning of the answer